# mysql query to get count joining 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

We have 3 tables

Table ticket

```
id | email
---+-----------------
1  | test@gmail.com
2  | test1@gmail.com
```

table customer

```
email           | location
----------------+----------
test@gmail.com  | Area1
test!@gmail.com | Area2
```

table zone

```
location | zone
---------+--------
Area1    | South
Area2    | North
```

I am trying to right query to output as

```
Count(ticket.id) | Zone
-----------------+-----------
 1               | South
 1               | North
```

Please give me a good suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple `join` with `group by`

```
select count(ticket.id), Zone 
from ticket 
join customer on ticket.email=customer.email 
join zone on customer.location=zone.location
group by zone
```

Comment: Thanks a lot was missing group by

Comment: @user2160698 if it helps feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer.